# display the current cascading drop data in sharepoint 2013 using knockout js

Tags: sharepoint, knockout.js, cascading

i want to create  cascading drop down lookup list in sharepoint 2013. i want to  take the data  ,whatever i  currently entered  that data will be displayusing knockout js in sharepoint 2013.
so please give me some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Develop your knockout js code in separate javascript file and add that page reference to master page. Make sure to give correct path. Finally publish the master page. After publishing
your code will look like as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="parthtothefolder/knockout-3.0.0.js">//<![CDATA[

 //]]>
 </script>

 <script src="parthtothefolder/yourfile.js">//<![CDATA[

    //]]>
 </script>
```

Add your html code to relevant location of the container.